# .NET + UIAutomation on Mac OSX?

Tags: .net, windows, macos, microsoft-ui-automation

Since .Net is ported and available on MacOS (as well as Linux) I wonder if they ported someting related to the UIAutomation library of windows. I know that MacOS has the Accessibility API but this is just another API.

Comment: No plan yet announced but you can keep an eye on it.

Comment: You can try [pyatom](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom) GUI automation library on Mac. Of course, the scripts on Mac will be different from Windows versions. We would want to have Apple Accessibility API as a back-end in [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) library, but there are no OS X experts in the team so far.

Comment: You do not need an expert. You need to write ObjectC and take at look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html. It bascially tells you all you need to know. So an old school non-swift iOS developer should be ready to give you a port.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It might be helpful though we're looking for the way to do it in pure Python.

Comment: You need to provide (an) extension module(s) that requires and provides the bridge and for this pridge you use ObjectC. I do not know of any other way :-). I have the same problem with Java... .